# Creating a Google compute instance group give me errors with terraform but is created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I am trying to add all the master VM instance on GCS in to a Google compute instance group via Terraform.

This is the code snipit that I use.

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "masters" {
  name        = "master-api"
  description = "Master API group"
  count = "${var.mastercount}"

  instances = ["${google_compute_instance.master.*.self_link}"]

  named_port {
    name = "api"
    port = "6443"
  }

  zone = "${"${var.region}-b"}"
}
```

When I apply the plan I do get my "master-api" group but I also get error output.
It looks to me that is trying to make more then one group.

```
Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

* google_compute_instance_group.masters[2]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_compute_instance_group.masters.2: Error creating InstanceGroup: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'projects/appportablityphase2/zones/us-east1-b/instanceGroups/master-api' already exists, alreadyExists
* google_compute_instance_group.masters[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_compute_instance_group.masters.0: Error creating InstanceGroup: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'projects/appportablityphase2/zones/us-east1-b/instanceGroups/master-api' already exists, alreadyExists
```

Comment: What happens if you run a destroy? Does the instance still stay there? If not does the error happen again if you run another apply?

Comment: Well I figured it out on my own.  I had to remove the count line.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR it destroys just fine.  The problem was the count.  It was trying to make more then one.

Comment: Can you add a proper answer where you explain the issue that you faced and your solution, it can be really useful for future users!

Comment: The problem here was that I had count in a group type.  So it was trying to create more then one compute group.  By removing the count line in the code it create just one and the problem went away.